# SQL query: self join on subquery necessitates creating a separate (non-temporary) table?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm working on what is for me a complicated query, and I've managed to get the information I need, but seem to be forced to create a table to accomplish it. I'm using MySQL, so I can't use `WITH`, I can't use a view because my `SELECT` contains a subquery in the `FROM` clause, and I can't use a temporary table because I need to self-join. Am I missing something?

Background:

- a `reservation` can have 1 or more `reservation_detail` (foreign key rel'p on `reservation_id`)
- a `reservation_detail` has a `quantity` and a `ticket_type` (foreign key rel'p on `ticket_type`)

Here's the first part of my current solution:

```
CREATE TABLE 
    tmp
SELECT 
    t.reservation_id, 
    t.ticket_type, 
    COALESCE(rd.quantity,0) AS qty
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        (ticket_type tt, reservation r)
    ) t
LEFT JOIN 
    reservation_detail rd 
    ON 
        t.reservation_id = rd.reservation_id 
    AND 
        t.ticket_type = rd.ticket_type;
```

This gives me a table that looks like the following, where for each combination of a `reservation_id` and a `ticket_type`, I have a `qty`.

```
+----------------+-------------+------+
| reservation_id | ticket_type | qty  |
+----------------+-------------+------+
|              1 | ADULT       |    2 | 
|              1 | CHILD       |    2 | 
|              1 | INFANT      |    0 | 
|              2 | ADULT       |    1 | 
|              2 | CHILD       |    0 | 
|              2 | INFANT      |    0 | 
|              3 | ADULT       |    1 | 
|              3 | CHILD       |    0 | 
|              3 | INFANT      |    0 | 
+----------------+-------------+------+
```

Now I can self join thrice on this table to get what I'm really looking for...

```
SELECT 
    t1.reservation_id, 
    t1.qty AS num_adults, 
    t2.qty AS num_children, 
    t3.qty AS num_infants
FROM 
    tmp t1
LEFT JOIN 
    tmp t2 
    ON 
        t1.reservation_id = t2.reservation_id
LEFT JOIN 
    tmp t3 
    ON 
        t2.reservation_id = t3.reservation_id
WHERE 
    t1.ticket_type = 'ADULT'
AND 
    t2.ticket_type = 'CHILD'
AND 
    t3.ticket_type = 'INFANT';
```

...which is one row for each reservation showing the qty for each of the three ticket types.

```
+----------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| reservation_id | num_adults | num_children | num_infants |
+----------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
|              1 |          2 |            2 |           0 | 
|              2 |          1 |            0 |           0 | 
|              3 |          1 |            0 |           0 | 
+----------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I hope this is enough information. Please leave a comment if it's not.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the speedy answers. I'm learning more about the power of a good SQL query every day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query is considering only these 3 types: ADULT, CHILD, INFANT; you don't have to use table ticket_type.

```
SELECT 
    r.reservation_id, 
    COALESCE(rd_adult.quantity,0) AS num_adults, 
    COALESCE(rd_child.quantity,0) AS num_children, 
    COALESCE(rd_infant.quantity,0) AS num_infants
FROM 
    reservation r
LEFT JOIN 
    reservation_detail rd_adult 
    ON r.reservation_id = rd_adult.reservation_id
       and rd_adult.ticket_type = 'ADULT'
LEFT JOIN 
    reservation_detail rd_child 
    ON r.reservation_id = rd_child.reservation_id
       and rd_child.ticket_type = 'CHILD'
LEFT JOIN 
    reservation_detail rd_infant
    ON r.reservation_id = rd_infant.reservation_id
       and rd_infant.ticket_type = 'INFANT'
```

Comment: Hi @manji, may I know this syntax also works in MySQL 5.7?  When I write the similar query, MySQL returns "ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '" LEFT JOIN 
    reservation_detail rd_child 
    ON" at line XXX.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with your first query, you can sub this for the 2nd:

```
SELECT reservation_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_type='ADULT' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS adults,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_type='CHILD' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS children,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_type='INFANT' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS infants,
FROM tmp
GROUP BY reservation_id;
```

However, I'm wondering a bit about your schema. You are storing `qty`, a calculated value. Have you considered just having a row for each ticket instance.  If you do that then  no tmp table is required, though you'd do the pivot similarly to the above.

Comment: Great, now I know how to use CASE! This certainly cleans/speeds up the second query (just missing commas after AS adults and AS children). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since table reservation_detail contains all the fields you need, you don't need to join the other tables and create a temp table.

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct
    t.reservation_id, 
    COALESCE(t1.qty,0) AS num_adults, 
    COALESCE(t2.qty,0) AS num_children, 
    COALESCE(t3.qty,0) AS num_infants
FROM reservation t
LEFT JOIN reservation_detail t1 ON t.reservation_id = t1.reservation_id AND t1.ticket_type = 'ADULT'
LEFT JOIN reservation_detail t2 ON t.reservation_id = t2.reservation_id AND t2.ticket_type = 'CHILD'
LEFT JOIN reservation_detail t3 ON t.reservation_id = t3.reservation_id AND t3.ticket_type = 'INFANT';
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but neither query works in my situation, because it is not necessarily true that a reservation contains a reservation_detail for each ticket type. These queries only work if all reservations have entries for each ticket type.

Comment: I updated my second query for your new requirement, try again.

Comment: Cleaned it up so there is only one query.

Comment: That does it for sure, and now is the same as najmeddine's answer. Thanks! I'd mark you both as accepted if I could.

Answer (score 0):

a simple GROUP BY should be OK:

```
SELECT t.reservation_id,
       SUM(CASE
              WHEN ticket_type = 'ADULT' THEN
               COALESCE(rd.quantity, 0)
              ELSE
               0
           END) num_adults,
       SUM(CASE
              WHEN ticket_type = 'CHILD' THEN
               COALESCE(rd.quantity, 0)
              ELSE
               0
           END) num_children,
       SUM(CASE
              WHEN ticket_type = 'INFANT' THEN
               COALESCE(rd.quantity, 0)
              ELSE
               0
           END) num_infants
  FROM (SELECT * FROM (ticket_type tt, reservation r)) t
  LEFT JOIN reservation_detail rd ON t.reservation_id = rd.reservation_id
                                 AND t.ticket_type = rd.ticket_type
 GROUP BY t.reservation_id
```

Comment: This works as well, thank you. I chose the other query as it is executing slightly faster on my test machine.